# Querying an SSRS server for report parameters via SOAP from an Azure App Service

Tags: c#, reporting-services, azure-web-app-service, ntlm

I'm attempting to do exactly what it says in the title; I have an SSRS server which I'm trying to connect to via SOAP in order to query for report parameters. Locally my code works fine, but when deployed to an app service in the same tenant it fails with the following error message:

"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'."

I can't share the exact code I'm using to connect, but it is along the lines of the "Basic Authentication" sample found in the Microsoft docs here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/net-framework/web-service-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15

To be clear, I am specifying domain, username and password. Its very hard to tell what's going wrong here, as the error message returned seems to be a "catch all" authentication failed message; I get the same message if I deliberately enter the wrong credentials locally. We definitely want to use NTLM authentication if possible, but it doesn't seem to want to make it easy for us!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? We are encountering the exact same issue. Our code works fine locally but we can't get it to work from our azure app service which runs on linux.